# How to find out result of elasticsearch parsing a query_string?

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

Is there a way to find out via the [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) API how a [query string query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/query-string-query/) is actually parsed? You can do that manually by looking at the [lucene query syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_5_0/queryparsersyntax.html), but it would be really nice if you could look at some representation of the actual results the parser has.

Comment: Have you tried enabling the explain output by adding explain=true to your search request?

Comment: @javanna Since purpose of explain=true is just to explain the rating of each individual result, that helps a little to guess what's happening. But I'd prefer something explicit, especially for complex cases.

Comment: Right, have a look at the [validate query api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/validate/) then, and use explain there too, should be better.

Comment: @javanna Good idea, but unfortunately validate's explanation just repeats the query.

Answer (score 6):

As javanna mentioned in comments there's [_validate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-validate.html) api. Here's what works on my local elastic (version 1.6):

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9201/pl/_validate/query?explain&pretty' -d'
{
  "query": {
      "query_string": {
      "query": "a OR (b AND c) OR (d AND NOT(e or f))",
      "default_field": "t"
    }
  }
}
'
```

`pl` is name of index on my cluster. Different index could have different analyzers, that's why query validation is executed in a scope of an index.

The result of the above curl is following:

```
{
  "valid" : true,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "explanations" : [ {
    "index" : "pl",
    "valid" : true,
    "explanation" : "filtered(t:a (+t:b +t:c) (+t:d -(t:e t:or t:f)))->cache(org.elasticsearch.index.search.nested.NonNestedDocsFilter@ce2d82f1)"
  } ]
}
```

I made one `OR` lowercase on purpose and as you can see in explanation, it is interpreted as a token and not as a operator.

As for interpretation of the explanation. Format is similar to `+-` [operators](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_boolean_operators) of `query string` query:

- ( and ) characters start and end `bool query`
- + prefix means clause that will be in `must`
- - prefix means clause that will be in `must_not`
- no prefix means that it will be in `should` (with `default_operator` equal to `OR`)

So above will be equivalent to following:

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "should" : [
      {
        "term" : { "t" : "a" }
      },
      {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term" : { "t" : "b" }
            },
            {
              "term" : { "t" : "c" }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "bool": {
          "must": {
              "term" : { "t" : "d" }
          },
          "must_not": {
            "bool": {
              "should": [
                {
                  "term" : { "t" : "e" }
                },
                {
                  "term" : { "t" : "or" }
                },
                {
                  "term" : { "t" : "f" }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I used `_validate` api quite heavily to debug complex `filtered` queries with many conditions. It is especially useful if you want to check how analyzer tokenized input like an url or if some filter is cached.

There's also an awesome parameter `rewrite` that I was not aware of until now, which causes the explanation to be even more detailed showing the actual Lucene query that will be executed.