# Elasticsearch long phrases search

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, nest

I'm using Elasticsearch for a full text search and I'm trying to find a better way to search for a long phrases.

For example i have a field "Seller" that can be up to 250 chars and i want to find all items with Seller = 'some seller name with spaces'.

If i understand correctly, in order to search text that contains spaces, i have to use NGramTokenizer that basically creates tokens like:

```
's', 'so', 'som', 'some', 'some ', 'some s' etc.
```

I know that i can define min and max gram, but i need to be able to search for 'a b', so my min gram has to be at least 3 and max gram as my field max length.

So i have to create a lot of tokens per one item, and it's only seller, but what about description with 4k chars?

This solution has a very low performance.

Can anyone suggest a better solution to work with long phrases with spaces?

My index settings:

```
analysis: {
  analyzer: {
    autoComplete: {
      filter: [
        "lowercase"
      ],
      type: "custom",
      tokenizer: "autoComplete"
    },
    caseInsensitive: {
      type: "custom",
      filter: [
        "lowercase"
      ],
      tokenizer: "keyword"
    }
  },
  tokenizer: {
    autoComplete: {
      type: "nGram",
      min_gram: "1",
      max_gram: "40"
    }
  }
},
```

I use "autoComplete" as an index analyzer and "caseInsensitive" as search analyzer

**EDIT:**

I use an NGramTokenizer in order to be able to search parts of the words

real word example:

```
Title: 'Huge 48" Bowtie LED Opti neon wall sign. 100,000 hours Bar lamp light'

search query: 'Huge 48" Bowt'
```

With whitespace tokenizer you can't search parts of the words if you search for a phrase.

Comment: Don't really understand why do you need ngrams. If you want to be able to search `"a b"` you need to have in your index either whole one token `a b` or two tokens `a` and `b`. This could be done with `whitespace` tokenizer, which would for text `a b c` make tokens: `a`, `b`, `c`. Don't see a need for ngrams here. Though I can see you're trying to do something with autocomplete, so maybe I don't understand your problem clearly.

Comment: Hi slawek, i've updated my post, hope now NGramTokenizer makes more sense.

Comment: I would suggest you to use shingles for phrase matching and nGrams for searching on parts of a word.

Comment: I use nGrams for searching on parts of a word, but there is an issue in indexing with nGrams on very long fields. Try to index with maxGram = 200+, it will take forever :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First question you need to answer is: do you need to match substrings within words. For example matching **miss** in trans**miss**ion. If you need this functionality then there's no better way to achieve it than ngrams. Trying to use wildcard at the beginning of the term, would mean going through every term in index to see if it matches and it doesn't scale well.

Note that you can use ngrams in two ways: as tokenizer or as token filter. Instead of the tokenizer you used, you could also use the token filter variant. First tokenize text with `standard` or `whitespace` tokenizer, then apply ngram token filter. With token filter you wouldn't have grams with spaces in your index. How often do you need to find text where there is a word that ends with `ing` and immediately after it there's a word that starts with `to`?

If you don't need to look inside of word, but sometimes want to left out the suffix, there are couple other options. First one is the other kind of grams, the [edge grams](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html), which are anchored at the beginning of the word. Most common use case scenario for edge ngrams is search-as-you-type functionality.

Below you can see example comparison of indexing (screenshot from [inquisitor](https://github.com/polyfractal/elasticsearch-inquisitor) plugin) `huge bowtie` using all those grams approaches (min: 2 max: 3):

[image]

Numbers by the tokens are important, they are position number. The position numbers are used when looking up phrases. Looking for phrase `"a b"` is essentially looking for the token `"a"` then looking for the token `"b"` and checking if their position difference is equal to 1. As you can see above, those grams resulting positions may cause some problems when looking up phrases.

First, let see how phrase queries would be interpreted for field analyzed in this way with query `"huge bowtie"` using [_validate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31460517/808271) API:

- edge_filter `"(hu hug huge) (bo bow bowt bowti bowtie)"`
- edge_tokenizer `"hu hug huge bo bow bowt bowti bowtie"`
- ngram_filter `"(hu hug ug uge ge) (bo bow ow owt wt wti ti tie ie)"`
- ngram_tokenizer `"hu hug ug uge ge bo bow ow owt wt wti ti tie ie"`

The tokenizer query interpretations are rather straightforward: instead of looking two tokens one after another, you have to look all the grams and make sure they are follow each other. The filter versions are more troublesome: query `"huge bowtie"` would match text `hu owt` because it's enough that at least one gram within word matches.

You must also be careful if you use analyzed queries and don't specify that you need phrase search. For example using `"query_string": { "query": "bowtie" }` will translate to `bo OR bow OR bowt OR bowt OR bowti OR bowtie` for edge ngrams, because default `query_string` operator is `OR`. That's rather not what user wanted because it will match anything with `bo`.

Notice also that if there is more that one token on the same position there is a problem that some phrases will match even though they shouldn't. For example phrase `"hu bowti"` would match with edge_filter and ngram_filter tokens even though there is no such phrase in source text.

It may seem that token filters variants of grams are inferior and not really useful. But when using gram token filters people [commonly](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_index_time_search_as_you_type.html#CO98-2) use different analyzer for searching than for indexing. For instance if we leave query `"huge bowtie"` as is without analyzing it, it would find match by looking up only 2 terms (because they are all in index, there's `huge:1` and `bowtie:2`). Using this approach though, you need to set n rather high (to be 100% sure everything will match it should be equal to the longest word). Otherwise you could have a situation when using max gram 5, where you wouldn't match `bowtie` search because index would contain only `bowti` token.

As you can see grams introduce quite complex problems. That's why people usually combine grams with normally indexed text (using [multi_field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/mapping-multi-field-type.html) mapping). Leaving yourself options later in future. Indexing the same text  with different analyzers allows to search in multiple ways and increase precision when using two fields in search at once.

If you don't want to deal with all those grams related problems. You could simply index text normally and use wildcards. You pay the price in search time, but depending on your data and scenarios, it could work.. Personally at my company we use wildcards to query indexes which have together couple billions documents and elastic handles it just fine.

If you decide to use wildcard queries you have couple options. You can use [wildcard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) query or [query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) query. But using them you won't be able to make phrase and wildcard suffix query at once. Hopefully there's match query variant which does exactly what you want: searches phrase with last word treated as not complete:

```
{
    "match_phrase_prefix" : {
        "message" : {
            "query" : "Huge 48" Bowt",
            "max_expansions" : 100
        }
    }
}
```

Excerpt from [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#_match_phrase_prefix):

> The match_phrase_prefix is the same as match_phrase, except that it
>   allows for prefix matches on the last term in the text.

**To sum it up.**

If I understand your case correctly, I would use edge tokenizer or my favourite edge token filter (with standard search analyzer) in a multifield with original text. Having original text allows to use lower values in edge grams.  Having such mapping you could use following query_string: `"originalText: \"Huge 48" Bowt\" OR edgeGrammed: \"Huge 38" Bowt\""`. You wouldn't have to worry that your n in edge gram is too low, because you have a fallback in original text. I think n equal to 10-15 should be enough? Also with original text wildcards are always an option.

[Here](http://blog.qbox.io/an-introduction-to-ngrams-in-elasticsearch) is a nice article about ngrams as well.

Comment: Hi slawek, thank you for such a thorough answer, you definitely gave me an idea to the final solution.

Comment: Glad I helped. It just comes to understanding what goes into index and how query is executed. In my company we have whole test suite for making sure analyzers work as we expect and another suite for testing such analysis allows for our desired searches. Tools I mentioned like analyser API,inquisitor and validate API help significantly to understand what is going on. Another tool you may look at Extended _analyze plugin http://stackoverflow.com/a/30943879/808271 . If you arrive at final solution,please consider posting it here and sharing it with community. I'm sure someone will find it useful.